# Настройка proxy под express js

Tags: node.js, express, proxy

Доброго времени суток! У меня следующий вопрос по express js. 
Нужно настроить proxy на картинку, лежащую по адресу http://www.somesite.ru/images/my_image.png
В результате запросы 
    *localhost:8080/images/good_image.png* 
и 
    *localhost:8080/image.png*
Должны отправлять на эту картинку. Реально ли это сделать в настройках **express-http-proxy** или нужен отдельный redirect? Не хочется менять URL при перенаправлении. Отрывок моего кода на данный момент:

app.get('/image.png',function (req,res){
    return res.redirect('/images/good_image.png');

app.use('/', proxy('http://www.somesite.ru/'));

Answer (score 0):

Использовать 301 редирект

```
res.writeHead(301, {'Location' : 'path_to_image'});
res.end();
```

Или

```
res.redirect(301, 'http://path_to_image' + req.ext)
```